Excel VBA macro for URL redirect detecting returns 200 instead of 301 sometimes
Column B contains the URLs
Column C is intended output for whether it's valid or not, or if it's a redirect
Column D, if it is a redirect, is what URL it redirects to
The following macro works well except there are occasional false positives. I found a few examples: https://www.samsung.com/us/support/troubleshooting/TSG01003149/
https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00080450/
https://www.samsung.com/us/support/troubleshooting/TSG01108764/
I expect these to be redirects but the macro outputs 200 for these for some reason. Why?
Here's the macro:
Sub CheckURLValidity()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim url As String
    Dim httpRequest As Object
    Dim responseCode As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ' Find the last row with data in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Create an HTTP request object
    Set httpRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    
    httpRequest.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = False

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        url = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        
        ' Check if the URL is empty
        If Len(url) > 0 Then
            httpRequest.Open "GET", url, False
            httpRequest.Send
            
            responseCode = httpRequest.Status

            ' Check the response code
            Select Case responseCode
                Case 200
                    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = "200 Valid"
                Case 404
                    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = "404 Not Found"
                Case 301
                    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = "301 Moved Permanently"
                    ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = httpRequest.getResponseHeader("Location")
                Case 302
                    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = "302 Found"
                    ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = httpRequest.getResponseHeader("Location")
                Case 307
                    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = "307 Temporary Redirect"
                    ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = httpRequest.getResponseHeader("Location")
                Case 308
                    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = "308 Permanent Redirect"
                    ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = httpRequest.getResponseHeader("Location")
                Case Else
                    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = responseCode & " - Other"
                    ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = httpRequest.getResponseHeader("Location")
            End Select
        End If
    Next i

    Set httpRequest = Nothing
End Sub

I've tried both true and false in this line, doesn't seem to make a difference:
httpRequest.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = False

What am I doing wrong and/or how can I update the macro to detect these redirects correctly?

It looks like you're using late binding, so have you defined a value for WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects somewhere?   Your code works fine for me with that added - those 3 URLs all return a 301 status.  FYI you can use HEAD in place of GET here, since you're not interested in the response body.

Isn't this line where the value is defined?
httpRequest.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = False
Now I'm even more stumped why it gives you 301 and gives me 200. @TimWilliams

Do you have Option Explicit at the top of your module?  Are you using late binding?  WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects is a constant, with a value of 6, but unless your VBA has a reference to the WinHttp.WinHttpRequest library, it's just going to see it as an undeclared variable and likely assign it a value of 0 (the value of WinHttpRequestOption_UserAgentString).   If you use Option Explicit it will save you from errors like that.

This is my first macro so I'm learning on the fly. The entire macro is copied into the question; I don't have Option Explicit at the top. I researched late binding and I believe I am using that since httpRequest is defined as Object - but I don't know how to adjust the code to not do that. @TimWilliams

Add Const WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects = 6 to the top right below Sub CheckURLValidity() 

@TimWilliams That worked perfectly! If you want to put it as an 'answer' instead of a comment I will mark it solved!

You're using late binding, so Excel VBA has no idea what WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects represents: it's seen as an undeclared variable and assigned a default value of zero.
Add
Const WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects = 6 

to the top right below Sub CheckURLValidity()
Also - use Option Explicit at the top of every module so this will get flagged up for you.

Also for anyone who doesn't see it in the other comment thread, the suggestion to change GET to HEAD definitely sped up the macro as well. Thanks again!
